# Reduction between problems in NP

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np

By definition, any problem in **NP** can be reduced to a problem in **NP-Complete**. However, let's say we have two arbitrary problems X and Y in **NP**. Is it necessarily true that X is reducible to Y?

I'm unclear on the aspect of reduction between two arbitrary problems of a particular complexity class, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: NP includes P, i.e., the easy problems, as well as NP-complete, i.e., the hard problems, as well as some things that are probably in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle there is no reason why an arbitrary problem should be reducible to another.

For a concrete example, it is known that factorization of an arbitrary integer with `n` bits is in `NP`, but it is is believed to both not be in `P` and not to be `NP`-complete.  Therefore traveling salesman is not reducible to integer factorization.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate has a list of other problems that are in the same category, and there is no reason to believe that, for example, graph isomorphism is reducible to factoring or vice versa.